# how to sum and subtotal by project code in vs 2005 reporting service

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2005, subtotal

I need to display the sub total for each project code as follow.I am using the VS2005 reporting service.

```
Code EmployeeName Projectcode Salary   TotalIncome  
                              Leave    TotalDetact 
000  Adam          ADM         1000      1000
                                100       100  
                   ELS         1100      1100
                                100       100

010 Eris           ADM        15000      15000
                                500        500

Subtotalfor        ADM         16000      16000    // I dont know how to do in here. 
Project                          600        600

2 persons 

1 person           ELS          1100       1100
                                 100        100
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to have a summary of the data by project at the end of the report? The problem is that you have multiple projects for people and you are ordering by person, so standard grouping won't work.

You have some alternatives:

1. Change the grouping to be project, then by person. Now you can summarize by project but of course you lose the person summary. Not ideal.
2. Create a second table in this report after the table you have in there now and do the summary there. You might want to create a new summary dataset for this table.
3. Use custom code (or a custom DLL) to do the calculating of the project summary for you. Right-click project surface-Properties-Code and you can write VBA functions in there that you can call from the table.
4. Use a subreport.

Option 2 is probably the easiest.